# How to write Logstash filter to filter kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

I want to use kafka as input and logstash as output. I will feed several topics into logstash, and want to filter according to topics. I tried to write the code like that:

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
        topics => ["test", "payment"]
      }
}

filter {
    if [topic] = "test" {
       //do something
    } else {
       //do something
    }
}
```

But seems it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the issue you're facing? Any kind of error? And are you missing an `s` in your `topic` filter which should be `topics` instead of `topic`?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `decorate_events` to add `kafka` field.

> Option to add Kafka metadata like topic, message size to the event. This will add a field named kafka to the logstash event containing the following attributes: topic: The topic this message is associated with consumer_group: The consumer group used to read in this event partition: The partition this message is associated with offset: The offset from the partition this message is associated with key: A ByteBuffer containing the message key

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-decorate_events

and then update conf like this

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => ["test", "payment"]
  }
}

filter {
  if [kafka][topic] = "test" {
   //do something
  } else {
   //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change input part by adding `decorate_events` to add `kafka` field.

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
        topics => ["test", "payment"]
        decorate_events => true
    }
}
```

Change filter part as follow:

```
filter {
    if [@metadata][kafka][topic] == "test" {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So both former answers had truth in it but were not correct.

**1. Add `decorate_events`:**

```
    input {
        kafka {
            bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
            topics => ["test", "payment"]
            decorate_events => true
        }
    }
```

2. Look for `[kafka][topic]` not for `[@metadata][kafka][topic]`:

```
    filter {
      if [kafka][topic] = "test" {
       //do something
      } else {
       //do something
      }
    }
```